# Render Python seaborn Plot on Django Template

Tags: python, django, seaborn

I am trying to render the plot generated by seaborn on Django template.

I have the following code in my views.py:

```
def booking_hour_plot():
    qs = bookings_today()
    df = read_frame(qs)
    plot = sns.countplot(data=df)
    return plot

def render_stats_page(request):
    #general info
    user_count = total_users_until_now()
    cancel_rate = activity_cancel_rate()

    #activity/booking details
    activity_set = activities_today()
    booking_set = bookings_today()
    plot = booking_hour_plot()

    return render(request, "stats.html", {'name':'Avonmore Statistics', 

    'total_user':int(user_count),
    'cancel_rate': round(float(cancel_rate), 2),
    'booking_count_today': booking_set.count(),
    'activity_count_today': activity_set.count(),

    'activities_today': activity_set,
    'bookings_today': booking_set,
    'booking_hour_plot': plot,
    
    })
```

And I have a html template called stats.html that containing the plot. The templates directory and views.py are in the same directory:

```
<li>Real Time Plot: {{booking_hour_plot}}</li>
```

However, the rendered html page is not really showing the plot. It's more like the plot object:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vdO.png)

Any Idea how to put the real plot on the html page, rather than this plot object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving and encoding your **plot** as `png` file, then display as `<img>` element *tag* by this way:

```
from io import BytesIO
import base64

def booking_hour_plot():
    qs = bookings_today()
    df = read_frame(qs)
    plot = sns.countplot(data=df)
    plot_file = BytesIO() 
    plot.savefig(plot_file, format='png')
    encoded_file = base64.b64encode(plot_file.getValue())
    return encoded_file
```

in `stats.html`:

```
<li>Real Time Plot: <img src='data:image/png;base64,{{booking_hour_plot}}'/></li>
```

Comment: hi, i have error: Unresolved attribute reference 'getValue' for class 'BytesIO'.  can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer of user1171 into a helperclass:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Img():
    def __init__(self):
            self.image = None

    def from_figure(self, input: plt.Figure):
        plot_file = BytesIO()
        input.savefig(plot_file, format='png')
        self.image = base64.b64encode(plot_file.getvalue()).decode()

    def to_html(self):
        return format_html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">', self.image)
```

Use as follows:

```
image = Img()
image.from_figure(plot.get_figure())
```

to html:

```
image.to_html()
```